# A Problem from Helmholtz Resonator Tutorial

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

To learn the methods used in the [Helmholtz Resonator tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/Acoustics/ModelCollection/HelmholtzResonator.html), I cut and pasted all the tutorial lines into a version 13.0 notebook, with a few comment lines to track with the tutorial discussion.

The first part operates fine, giving a matching theoretical resonance at 175.454 Hz. But when I go on to the numerical solution for the pressure, I get different results than the tutorial. Particularly important is the frequency response plot, which shows resonances at around 350 Hz (instead of 180 Hz as in the tutorial) and a bigger peak at 3694 Hz that is not present in the tutorial.  I can't find any mistakes in my cut/paste lines; can anyone see what is going wrong?

```
(* Helmholtz Resonator Bottle example *)
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];

(* Define geometric parameters to be used*)
l = 0.05;
Subscript[r, neck] = 0.01;
Subscript[r, cavity] = 0.05;

(*Define a RegionUnion between the neck and cavity cross-section*)
Subscript[Ω, neck] = Rectangle[{0, -l}, {Subscript[r, neck], 0}];
Subscript[Ω, cavity] = Disk[{0, -(l + Subscript[r, cavity] -
  Subscript[r, neck]/2)}, Subscript[r, cavity], {3 Pi/2, 5 Pi/2}];
Subscript[Ω, bottle] = RegionUnion[Subscript[Ω, cavity], Subscript[Ω, neck]];

(*Sound medium is Air*)
Subscript[c, air] = QuantityMagnitude[ThermodynamicData["Air", "SoundSpeed"]];
Subscript[ρ, air] = QuantityMagnitude[ThermodynamicData["Air", "Density"]];

(*Set up a 2D axisymmetric Helmholtz equation*)
vars = {p[r, z], ω, {r, z}};
pars = <|"MassDensity" -> Subscript[ρ, air], 
   "SoundSpeed" -> Subscript[c, air], 
   "RegionSymmetry" -> "Axisymmetric"|>;
AcousticModel = AcousticPDEComponent[vars, pars];
(*Set the frequency range: evenly space on log scale 0.1 to 6 kHz*)
{Subscript[f, min], Subscript[f, max]} = {0.1, 6000};
fRange = Table[
   10^f, {f, Log10[Subscript[f, min]], 
    Log10[Subscript[f, 
      max]], (Log10[Subscript[f, max]] - Log10[Subscript[f, min]])/
     499}];

(*Define corrected length as in Pierce, Resonance freq expected *)
Subscript[l, t] = l + 0.82 Subscript[r, neck];
Subscript[f, r] = 
 Subscript[c, air]/(2*Pi)*
  Sqrt[Subscript[r, neck]^2/(Subscript[l, t]*4/3*
      Subscript[r, cavity]^3)]
Nearest[fRange, Subscript[f, r]]

(*Specify pressure at top of neck *)
Subscript[Γ, D] = 
  AcousticPressureCondition[z == 0, vars, 
   pars, <|"AcousticPressure" -> 1|>];

(* Specify PDE with model parameters and boundary conditions*)
pde = {AcousticModel == 0, Subscript[Γ, D]};
(*Specify a helper function for computing max grid size*)
MaxGridSize[c_, ω_, Resolution_] := 
  Module[{λ}, λ = 2 π c/ω;
   λ/Resolution];
Options[AcousticsOptions] = {"Resolution" -> 60};
AcousticsOptions[c_, ω_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
     "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> {"Length" -> 
          MaxGridSize[c, ω, OptionValue["Resolution"]]}}}}

(*Set up and solve the PDE at different frequencies*)
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[pde, 
   p, {r, z} ∈ 
    Subscript[Ω, bottle], {ω}, 
   AcousticsOptions[Subscript[c, air], ω]];
Monitor[pfunTable = 
   Table[pfun[ω] /. {ω -> (2 π) f}, {f, fRange}], 
  Row[{"frequency being solved = ", CForm[f], " Hz"}]];

(*Create function to find the nearest freq index for given input*)
findNearestFrequencyIndex = Nearest[fRange -> "Index"];

(*Get position index of solution corresponding to 6 kHz*)
index = First[findNearestFrequencyIndex[6000]];

(*Check value of the closest frequency at that index *)
fRange[[index]];

(*Visualize pressure distribution at 6 kHz*)
DensityPlot[
  Re[pfunTable[[index]][r, z]], {r, z} ∈ 
   Subscript[Ω, bottle], 
  Sequence[PlotRange -> 
    MinMax[Re[Part[pfunTable, index]["ValuesOnGrid"]]], 
   ColorFunction -> 
    ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", 
      MinMax[Re[Part[pfunTable, index]["ValuesOnGrid"]]]}], 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
   PlotPoints -> 80, FrameLabel -> {"r", "z"}, 
   PlotLabel -> Row[{"p(r,z) at ", Part[fRange, index], " Hz"}], 
   PlotLegends -> 
    BarLegend[{Automatic, 
      MinMax[Re[Part[pfunTable, index]["ValuesOnGrid"]]]}, 50, 
     LegendLabel -> "[Pa]"], ImageSize -> Medium]];

(*Sound-pressure level in dB - define the reference value*)
Subscript[p, ref] = 20*10^-6;

(* visualize sound pressure level at f=1123.1 Hz*)
index = First[findNearestFrequencyIndex[1123.1]];

(*Plot it *)
DensityPlot[
  20*Log[10, 
    Sqrt[0.5*pfunTable[[index]][r, z]*
       Conjugate[pfunTable[[index]][r, z]]]/Subscript[p, ref]], {r, 
    z} ∈ Subscript[Ω, bottle], 
  Sequence[PlotRange -> 
    MinMax[20 Log[
       10, (1/Subscript[p, 
           ref]) Sqrt[(0.5 Part[pfunTable, index][
             "ValuesOnGrid"]) Conjugate[
           Part[pfunTable, index]["ValuesOnGrid"]]]]], 
   ColorFunction -> 
    ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", 
      MinMax[20 Log[
         10, (1/Subscript[p, 
             ref]) Sqrt[(0.5 Part[pfunTable, index][
               "ValuesOnGrid"]) Conjugate[
             Part[pfunTable, index]["ValuesOnGrid"]]]]]}], 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
   PlotPoints -> 90, FrameLabel -> {"r", "z"}, 
   PlotLabel -> 
    Row[{"Sound Pressure Level at ", Part[fRange, index], " Hz"}], 
   PlotLegends -> 
    BarLegend[{Automatic, 
      MinMax[20 Log[
         10, (1/Subscript[p, 
             ref]) Sqrt[(0.5 Part[pfunTable, index][
               "ValuesOnGrid"]) Conjugate[
             Part[pfunTable, index]["ValuesOnGrid"]]]]]}, 50, 
     LegendLabel -> "[dB]"], ImageSize -> Medium]];

(*Define the region of integration as a mesh*)
mesh = ToElementMesh[Subscript[Ω, cavity]];

(*Calculate the volume of the cavity V*)
volume = NIntegrate[1, {r, z} ∈ mesh];

(*Define integral and get average pressure over all frequencies*)
pavg = Table[{fRange[[i]], (1/volume)*
     NIntegrate[
      Abs[pfunTable[[i]][r, z]], {r, z} ∈ mesh]}, {i, 
    Length[fRange]}];

(*Visualize freq response using log-log scale*)ListLinePlot[pavg, 
 GridLines -> {{Subscript[f, r]}}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log10", "Log10"}, 
 Sequence[PlotTheme -> "Scientific", PlotRange -> Automatic, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed], 
  PlotLegends -> {"Frequency sweep"}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Frequency response", 
  FrameLabel -> {"Frequency [Hz]", "Average |p| [Pa]"}]]
```

Here is the frequency response plot I get:

[image]

while the tutorial shows

[image]

So, I am baffled by the difference.  The tutorial shows the right resonance, I believe, according to basic acoustics, at 180 Hz.  But the same tutorial lines performed in V.13.0 give a quite different frequency-response result -- different resonance peaks and higher values. Why?

Comment: If I run it in `13.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)`, I get the same (wrong) plot as you. But if I run it in `13.2.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2022)` (Wolfram Cloud), I get the (correct) plot as in the tutorial ... Therefore, this seems like a bug that has already been fixed ...

Comment: That's nice to know, kind of.  Thanks for taking the trouble to try it.  I wonder if there is a workaround available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem arises due to `"RegionSymmetry"` option being available only from version 13.2 (or perhaps 13.1, I am not sure). Curiously, it is even not mentioned in the current documentation for [`AcousticPDEComponent`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AcousticPDEComponent.html).

Compare the following in v12.3 and v13.2:

```
AcousticPDEComponent[{p[r, z], ω, {r, z}}, <||>]
```

$$\nabla _{\{r,z\}}\cdot \left(\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -1 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)\cdot\nabla _{\{r,z\}}p(r,z)\right)-\omega ^2 p(r,z) \qquad \text{v12.3 and v13.2}
$$

```
AcousticPDEComponent[{p[r, z], ω, {r, z}}, <|"RegionSymmetry" -> "Axisymmetric"|>]
```

$$\begin{align}
\nabla _{\{r,z\}}\cdot \left(\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -1 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)\cdot \nabla _{\{r,z\}}p(r,z)\right)-\omega ^2 p(r,z) & \qquad\text{v12.3} \\
\nabla _{\{r,z\}}\cdot \left(\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -1 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right).\nabla _{\{r,z\}}p(r,z)\right)\color{crimson}{+\left\{-\frac{1}{r},0\right\}\cdot\nabla _{\{r,z\}}p(r,z)} -\omega ^2 p(r,z) & \qquad\text{v13.2}
\end{align}
$$

As you can see, v12.3 simply ignores `"RegionSymmetry"` option (without any warning!), and the red term that corrects for the cyllindrical coordinates is missing.

You can fix the code by manually correcting `AcousticModel`:

```
AcousticModel = {-(1/r)*1/Subscript[ρ, air], 0} . 
   Inactive[Grad][p[r, z], {r, z}] - (1/(Subscript[ρ, air]*
     Subscript[c, air]^2)) ω^2 p[r, z] - 
   Inactive[Div][({{1/Subscript[ρ, air], 0}, {0, 1/Subscript[ρ, air]}} . 
     Inactive[Grad][p[r, z], {r, z}]), {r, z}]
```

[image]

Comment: The same problem occurred in the Wine Bottle continuation of that tutorial, and Domen's redefined AcousticModel, which correctly handles the cylindrical symmetry, fixes it.

Comment: @DeanLangley, the RegionSymmetry parameter was introduced in 13.2, so versions before that can not generate the PDE automatically. In the system reference documentation there is a 'New in Version' type of thing for the application models; unfortunately that does not display on the web. So if you find something in the web ref pages make sure that the document is also present in your system documentation, that way you are sure that all functionality is available.

Comment: @Domen (+1), none of the PDE model parameters can create a warning. If you wanted to combine an AcousticsPDEComponent with SomeOtherPDEComponent and that made use of a parameter "X" you would not want AcousticPDEComponent to give a message just because "X" is not relevant for the acoustic part.

Comment: @user21, thanks for the clarification. I have not used `*PDEComponent` much yet so I did not know that the properties from different `*PDEComponent`s must somehow get combined (?) if they are used together. Anyhow, I also wrote to Wolfram Support suggesting that a note is given to the beginning of the tutorials for the minimal version needed. Because otherwise, it is a real shame that such a nice tutorial can be evaluated without any problems in an older version, yet getting different results without any notices or warnings (which we are used to if symbols/options are not present) :)

Comment: I updated the AcousticPDEComponent ref page to now also contain notes about the RegionSymmetry, like other PDEComponents do. That was an oversight on my part. Sorry about that. The updated ref page will be available in (the upcoming) version 13.3

Comment: These tutorials are very helpful to me.  Thanks for the future update and your comments here.